# Why can't all Functors be Monads?

Tags: java, haskell, functional-programming, monads, vavr

To my knowledge, Functors are those which have `map()` and Monads are those which also have `flatMap()`.
All Monads are Functors but not vice-versa. What prevents Functors to implement a `flatMap()` and be a Monad?
Are there any Functors which stayed that way due to some limitation. Can you please provide some examples. Thanks.

Comment: https://www.xanthir.com/b4fM0

Answer (score 4):

The statement *all monads are functors* means that, using only the methods from Monad, we can implement the methods from Functor. This can indeed be done, which is why we say that all monads are functors. I don’t know Vavr, but here’s some code in Haskell which does this:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}

instance Monad m => Functor m where
    fmap f x = x >>= (\x' -> return (f x'))
```

By contrast, the statement *all functors are monads* means that, using only the methods from Functor, we can implement the methods from Monad. And this can’t be done, since you can do things with monads which you can’t do with functors. So we say that not all functors are monads.

Comment: Is this pseudo Haskell? I cannot declare a Functor instance: "Illegal instance delaration for `Functor m`". https://repl.it/repls/TiredThunderousMigration

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann `{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, UndecidableInstances #-}
` is required for this kind of instance declaration. Those are pretty common language extensions, you'll actually find them on (my estimate) half of all Haskell source files. (But even with those extensions, it will of course give errors if you write that instance, because it conflicts with directly-declared `Functor` instances.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Thanks for editing that in! It looks like you’ve been correcting many of my other answers lately, so thank you for those ones as well!

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I did intend it to be somewhat ‘pseudo Haskell’. You can’t actually define such an instance because it conflicts with many other Functor instances for types with already-defined Monad instances, but it shows that such an instance _can_ be defined in a way that typechecks and (sort-of) works. A better example would have been to define a new function `monad_fmap :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b`, and implement that instead of `fmap`.

Comment: @bradrn `monad_fmap` a.k.a. `liftM`. :)

Comment: @WillNess I know this already exists as `liftM`. I just wanted to make the name absolutely clear even for people who may not know about `liftM`.

Comment: so it's good to be made aware of it, right? seeing something from several POVs often helps to see it clearer.

Comment: Good point @WillNess! I thought you were just correcting me, but you’re right in that different POVs are important.

Answer (score 1):

If a type implements `flatMap()` (as well as `return()/unit()/emit()/inject()/wrap()/...`), it is already a Monad, by definition.

A "Functor" is a very narrow view of a given type. It only considers its ability to `map()`. There's no regard to any specifics of the given type, when regarding it as an instance of "Functor".

If a given type can have a **law-abiding**<sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> `flatMap()` implemented (as well as `return()`), then it can also be viewed as a lawful instance of "Monad".

If an opaque type does not supply us with `return()`, it can't be viewed as a Monad, is one possibility.

Another is `flatMap()` which does not follow the Monad laws.

*edit:* <sup>(</sup>*<sup>)</sup> thanks to [@leftaroundabout](https://stackoverflow.com/users/745903/leftaroundabout) for pointing out about the laws. on the other hand declaring an unlawful Monad instance in Haskell is still technically possible, even though it's certainly not advisable.